# jQuery cors ajax request failing

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, cors

I'm trying to fire a cors ajax request with jQuery towards a different port in the same machine, below is my code (my application is running on an appache server on port 80):

JS:

```
$(function(){
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sys_monitor/ccn",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        data : {a: '11'},
        success : function(res){
            alert(res);
            $('#stage').html(res);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, text, exception){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert ('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert ('The requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert ('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert ('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert ('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert ('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert ('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
        });
```

Servlet ("post" is written to the console) running on tomcat (eclipse) on port 8080:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().write("hello there");
    System.out.println("post");
}
```

using firebug I can see the request (with response code 200) and content length 11 (empty result tab), but the error function is being executed with XHR status 0

(side question1: why is firebug displaying "xml" as type ?):

(side question2: why isn't there an OPTIONS request before the POST ?):

[image: firebug]

I also tried with RESTClient plugin for firefox, and I'm getting the wanted result:

[image: RESTClient plugin]

all help/tips is welcome

Comment: so, did you actually enable CORS?

Comment: how do we do that ? I thought this line **jQuery.support.cors = true;** would do it

Comment: Are you getting the same behavior when running on Chrome, the XHR object need to read the HTTP status response in order to return the proper (status's) code.
I doubt this happens when you are on local machine

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: thanks @DavidFregoli, it's very embarrassing, I already visited that site but didn't pay attention to it :p ; the line **response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");** in the **doPost** method will solve the issue. please make this as an answer so that I accept it.

PS: any ideas about the side questions ?

Comment: an options request won't be sent unless your request meets certain pre-flight requirments. For simple requests you don't need pre-flight. [This is a great explanation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Answer (score -3):

Check this question 
[XmlHttp Request status 0, localhost issues (javascript, ajax, php) help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338506/xmlhttp-request-status-0-localhost-issues-javascript-ajax-php-help),

it looks like a browser issue dealing with localhost

Comment: The question you referenced deals with an unexpected cross-origin call.  That is not what is happening here at all.

Comment: indeed it is related to cross-orgin call and exactly to the browser implementation of it